# If a fizzy drink was poured in zero gravity what will happen?

Tags: experimental-physics

What will happen if I pour some soda in zero gravity ?

Comment: This may be educational: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgC-ocnTTto

Comment: You just might end up wearing some of your fizzy drink for the rest of your flight.

Comment: Can you define the term "pour" in the context of zero gravity? The term usually means causing a liquid to fall out of a container due to gravity.

Answer (score 3):

NASA  have done some work on this and, from their website: [NASA and Fizzy Drinks](http://www.nasa.gov/audience/foreducators/5-8/features/F_Carbonated_Beverages_Space.html)

> The bubbles of carbon dioxide in carbonated beverages aren't buoyant in a weightless environment, so they remain randomly distributed throughout the fluid, even after swallowing. This means that carbonated beverages including soft drinks and beer may become a foamy mess during space travel.
>   (Quote)  "Carbonated drinks currently don't make the trip because the carbonation and the soda will not separate in microgravity. Some experiments have been done with special microgravity dispensers for soda, but it has not been perfected yet."
>   Even if a microgravity dispenser is perfected, there is no guarantee that carbonated beverages will be used in space. In space, with the absence of gravity, the carbon dioxide bubbles in carbonated beverages go through an astronaut's digestive system, rather than being belched out as on Earth, and may cause adverse side effects.

NASA is imo, being very polite here, a small space capsule, *adverse side effects*, not a good mixture, even in the ISS after a few drinks.

Comment: _The bubbles...aren't buoyant_.  One effect not mentioned in your answer is that when you uncap a bottled beverage, the bubbles _grow_.  If they grow slowly enough (e.g., because the liquid is cold, and because there aren't very many bubbles to begin with) then they float harmlessly to the surface.  If you shake the bottle before opening though, the bubbles grow faster, and we all know what happens next.  In microgravity, where the bubbles don't float to the surface, there is no _slowly enough_.